# 1973 Tappan gas range with pilots no electronic parts

Tags: gas, oven

Old Tappan range oven worked 7 years ago. Stove top works fine but pilots won't stay lit. Oven pilot lights, but oven burner won't ignite. 
Doesn't seem to be getting gas to oven burner.
No gas leaks. No propane odor.
Could gas line connected to oven temperature knob down to oven burner be clogged?
Or could it be little component in bottom of broiler with oven pilot gas line and oven temperature gas lines enter and exit to the oven pilot and oven burner?

Answer (score 0):

With a standing flame I have had similar issues and even though my wife is a clean freak it was because the pilot assembly was dirty. I was able to clean things up with green Scotch-Brite, but after doing that thought steel wool would have been better (any of the debris I may have left in could melt and plug the orifice). The pilot assembly had a shield and I have no idea how stuff got back in there and caused the problems, but after cleaning the assembly and the burner with a wire brush it worked fine until we sold that house. Newer ovens have hot surface igniters and safeties that our old one did not have. That stove top and oven did not have thermocouple safeties like most pilots on water heaters and furnaces. If you have a thermocouple, it could be the problem. A model # would help here to know for sure.

Comment: I would think older stoves would have a thermocouple that only opens the gas valve if it senses a flame.

Comment: @duston how do you light the pilot then? Being an older individual even having experience with old stoves that had no gas valve but did have a pilot. Every gas valve I have worked with has ether a position or a button that has to be pushed to turn on the gas the pilot is lit and you have to hold the button to allow the thermocouple to heat up and open the valve after that the valve can be turned on.

Comment: I was thinking the thermocouple controlled the main burner, not the pilot.  That was an issue as I recall, if the pilot blew out, there was the possibility of gas buildup.

Comment: @duston this is why most have a button to push or a pilot only position for lighting that is usually spring loaded to a pilot position that uses the TC if it blows out the button has to be pushed or in the pilot position there are several different methods but with modern 7 year old gas valves they usually control the pilot also.